# Angular ui route doesn't activate the controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

In the following view

```
<div ng-repeat="make in makes | orderBy: 'name'">
  <a ui-sref="modal.models({make: make._id})">
    <li>{{make.name}}</li>
  </a>
</div>
```

I click on a `li` and I should send `_id` to `ModelsModalController`. Unfortunately even if the url in the browser appears correctly when I click on the li element the controller is not called

```
(function() {
  'use strict';

  angular
    .module('App.modal', [
      'App.modal.controllers',
    ])
    .config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
      $stateProvider
        .state('modal', {
          url: '/modal',
          templateUrl: 'modules/modal/partials/modal.html',
          controller: 'MakesModalController'
        })
        .state('modal.models', {
          url: '/models?make',
          templateUrl: 'modules/modal/partials/modal.models.html',
          controller: 'ModelsModalController'
        });
    });
})();
```

in the browser it appears something like `#/modal/models?make=id_number` but the controller is not called

here are my controllers

```
(function() {
  'use strict';

  angular
    .module('App.modal.controllers', [])
    .controller('MakesModalController', ['$scope', 'Makes', function($scope, Makes) {
      Makes.get(function success(response) {
          $scope.makes = response;
        },
        function error(errorResponse) {
          console.log('Error:' + JSON.stringify(errorResponse));
        });
    }])
    .controller('ModelsModalController', ['$scope', '$stateParams', function($stateParams, $scope) {
      console.log('hello');
    }]);
})();
```

Comment: unfortunately it doesn't work what you have suggested

Comment: Are there any error on your console? Does the template for the view exist? (can you see it being retrieved in your network tab, or if you are injecting it into the template cache, can you find it manually).  Does the parent template (`modules/modal/partials/modal.html`) have `ui-view` tag in it (telling ui-router where the child view is to be inserted)?

Comment: @TheSharpieOne The reason was probably because I haven't inserted into the nested view ui-view as you suggested above. now I have refactored the code and works like a charm. Thank you. please post your answer and I will be glad to accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because your views are nested, you need to specific where the child state view should be inserted into the parent state view.

Based on the code you provided in the question, your parent state view looks like

```
<div ng-repeat="make in makes | orderBy: 'name'">
  <a ui-sref="modal.models({make: make._id})">
    <li>{{make.name}}</li>
  </a>
</div>
```

There is no `ui-view` inside of that view and ui-router has no idea where you want the child view to go... so it doesn't render it and thus your controller is never called.

Try adding `ui-view` somewhere in the parent view

```
<ui-view />
<div ng-repeat="make in makes | orderBy: 'name'">
  <a ui-sref="modal.models({make: make._id})">
    <li>{{make.name}}</li>
  </a>
</div>
```

**OR** do not nest the states.

```
.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
  $stateProvider
    .state('modal', {
      url: '/modal',
      templateUrl: 'modules/modal/partials/modal.html',
      controller: 'MakesModalController'
    })
    .state('models', {
      url: '/models?make',
      templateUrl: 'modules/modal/partials/modal.models.html',
      controller: 'ModelsModalController'
    });
});
```

(and update references from `modal.models` to `models` where needed)

Answer (score -2):

Change the declaration of your controller to `.module('App.modal.controllers')` get rid of the [].

And you should try this `url: '/models?:make'` in the  state declaration

Comment: The first suggestion is totally wrong. I need to define it. so it is a setter not a getter

Comment: I tell you twice that what you say is totally wrong

Comment: for debugging purpose could you listen to the `$stateChangeStart`  on `$rootScope` and see if the state `modal.models` has `ModelsModalController` as controller